# Transferring cell values to another (variable) worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hoping you can help!  I'm fairly new to VBA and most of what I've picked up is from this excellent forum!

I've created a workbook to capture information for our church finances.
i.e. for each transaction we capture various values (date, amount, debit/credit, cheque details, which bank account etc).  This is in a worksheet called "DataEntry"

Once info has been entered I'm looking to transfer it to one of three worksheets (Bank A/C "A", "B" or "C"), dependant on the account that has been selected (i.e. "which bank account" value).

I've created a command button on the DataEntry sheet and have been able to use VBA to pick up which Bank Account worksheet to open and then to go to the next blank row.  I've also been able to paste data from one field (date) in the data entry sheet into the first blank cell of the bank account worksheet.

I'm struggling though on how to then move to the next column in the same row, go back to the dataentry worksheet and select/copy the next corresponding field, and repeat this until all data entry fields have been captured into the correct worksheet in a row.

I'm sure this is something that people use Excel for all the time - i.e. data entry form front end - populating worksheets in the back end.  But I can't see how to do this.

I would really appreciate any guidance on this you can provide.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: this is a snip of the code I believe does the paste    Sheets("DataEntry").Select
         LDate = Range("C3").Value
         LDebitCredit = Range("C9").Value
         LChequeInfo = Range("c11").Value
               
        Range("c3").Select
        Selection.Copy
    
Worksheets(sSheetName).Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
   
    erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    activecells= (erow, 2)